# Se puede en Delphi declarar un TDictionary con gerenricos?

Tags: delphi, genericos

se puede en Delphi hacer la siguiente declaración?

```
TDictionary<T, TList<T>>
```

El compilador no me deja argumentando:

> Undeclared identifier: 'T'

tengo agregado en el uses

> System.Generics.Collections;

Answer (score 1):

Claro que puedes... pero debes especificar a que tipo representa T.

Ejemplo:

> ```
> var  a:TDictionary<string,TList<Tcomponent>>;
>
> begin
>      a:=TDictionary<string,TList<Tcomponent>>.Create(10);
> end;
> ```

Queda más claro si defines un tipo sobre todo la definición del genérico.

En la sección declaración:

```
 MiTipo=TDictionary<string,TList<Tcomponent>>;
```

En el cuerpo del procedimiento:

```
 var  a:MiTipo;
      
    begin
      a:=MiTipo.Create(10);
    end;
```